# how to convert string to vector<int> c++

Tags: c++, string, vector, integer

I would like to convert an string into a vector, so that it looks like the following:

```
string number = "0110";
vector < int > Vec;
```

with the result:

```
Vec[0] = 0 
Vec[1] = 1
Vec[2] = 1
Vec[3] = 0
```

My problem is that the number starts with a 0, so using % doesn't seem to work if i first transform my string to an int

Comment: numbers don't deal with leading zeroes. You sure you can't use a string?

Comment: If you know the length of the digit, you can use for-loop with % operator.

Comment: yes sorry, actually read it and save as string, I transformed it to int because I thought it was the first step

Comment: Is `Vec[0]` the most significant digit from your string? Or your least significant? Hard to tell with that palindrome you got there.

Comment: Think of the advantages of leaving it a string. It's already chopped up into digits, no math is needed to split it up, you just need to iterate the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the question is modified to make it answerable:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    string number = "0110";
    vector < int > Vec;
    for(char& digit : number){
        Vec.push_back(digit - '0');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code would not compile due to omitting namespace `std`

Comment: @Slava Oh, You are right, I will add it ASAP.

Comment: If at all, it's better to put `using namespace std` *inside* `main`.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis You are right. but as this code is for just demonstration purpose, as long as it compiles, it is up to the user to modify it for their needs.

Comment: "as long as it compiles, it is up to the user to modify it for their needs" I think it is better not to propagate bad habits in answer as it can be used by novice programmers as recommendations of code writing style.

Comment: @Slava Got your point. I will modify it then.